# Can I get Lync to save all conversations

Tags: lync

Lync does not save the conversations by default as normal IM applications do. Once the window is closed, the conversation is lost and cannot be recovered, unless one has saved it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> at some point. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: There is an option to save conversation in the options menu of Lync.  have you enabled this option?

Comment: @Ramhound, I am risking to look stupid, but I will say it. I searched for that option - did not find it. Could you help me with that? Screenshot would be amazing

Comment: See [LyncIMLocalHistory](https://github.com/bujocek/LyncIMLocalHistory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this site](http://www.unr.edu/it/communications/lync/start/im/save):

> 1. In the main Lync window, click the Options "Gear" icon.
> 2. From the list on the left, select Personal.
> 3. Check the box labeled Save IM conversations in my email Conversation History folder and then click OK.
> 4. Conversations will be automatically saved to the Conversation History folder in your e-mail.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the answer. What do I do if it is greyed out?

Comment: @vembutech - You are either not using an Exchange backend or your IT department has disabled this feature.

Comment: I love my IT department... Thanks for the info though

Comment: Plagiarized: http://www.unr.edu/it/communications/lync/start/im/save